# How can I build a NetBeans project outside of NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build, glassfish-3

I have a Java EE 6 project I'm developing in NetBeans.  All of the ant configuration was created automatically by NetBeans and I haven't touched it.  Everything builds and deploys using NetBeans with no problem.

Our typical mode of operation with other projects is that the developers will tag a particular build when it's ready to ship, then our operations support team will run a script to export that build from CVS, create the necessary deployment assets, then copy/deploy those assets to production.

I'm trying to fit into this model with my NetBeans project.  How can I build this project (developed on a Windows desktop) using a vanilla jdk/ant/Glassfish installation on a Solaris server?  I do not have NetBeans installed on this server, as it is a headless box used to host our integration environment.

I've started looking through the ant XML files and it seems to be a tangled mess of dependencies on files that have paths defined for files on my Windows system.  Is there some straightforward way to just build this project on another box outside of NetBeans?  Failing that, what would be a more typical build/deployment model that falls into a 3-tier support system, where developers are not supposed to be touching production systems?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Any chance you found a real answer? I want to do the same - build a netbeans project without a human (ie from a script) (I'm happy to have netbeans installed)

Comment: I ended up taking the ant build process used by NetBeans and gutting it down to the bare minimum code, which enabled me to run my builds outside of NetBeans.  You can start with the stuff NetBeans creates in your project and just strip that down.  I don't recall the process taking very long.  I'd post a copy of my results, but I've long since left the company, so I no longer have access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the main Ant/Maven/whatever build files should be hand-crafted to do what you actually need, and completely removed from all IDE/directory structure/etc. dependencies.

NetBeans/Eclipse/IntelliJ can all use a properly-configured Ant file, but they can't necessarily (ever?) use one generated by another IDE, nor can humans/CI servers.

Another option is to create a build script specifically for production/CI/etc. deployment; we've done both depending on actual needs/who can touch what/etc.

Comment: NetBeans can open Maven files directly. So that should be the "common denominator" between IDE and "non-IDE"

Comment: Except that he's talking about Ant, but yes, I agree: projects should be buildable, repeatedly, from the command line, across environments/desktops.

Comment: So if I read you right, what you're basically saying is: Learn ant, write your own build files, and ignore (or throw away) the stuff NetBeans created.

Comment: Yep (although I could be wrong :) It's just more convenient in the long run: people not running NetBeans can use it, CI servers w/ no IDE at all can use it, etc.

Comment: If you rely on the scripts that netbeans generates then there are some dependencies on ant-netbeans jar files as well (I'm pretty sure that the other IDE's do similar). For repeatable builds in different environments I really think Maven is worth evaluation

Comment: Maven's worth consideration, but not because it's any more cross-environment than Ant is :)

Comment: For now I went with the ant approach, because it was the path of least resistance, though I do intend to research maven once I get some time.  What I did was copy the user-specific build.properties file, remove the stuff that wasn't relevant to my project, then defined the paths as needed for building on my server.  After that I wrote a simple server-build.xml file that only had the tasks I needed (simple tasks to init, compile, dist, and clean).  Now I can run builds on the server with "ant -f server-build.xml" and it all works just fine.  Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Comment: Yep, IMO that's the best approach. (But I almost always use a different IDE than everyone else ;)